# TortoiseSVN hanging on Win7 when tagging from a branch

Tags: windows, svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn, tagging

I am attempting to create a release tag (01.02.03) from a code branch (01.02), however everytime I use the 'Copy To' and provide the path to copy the code to for tagging TortoiseSVN hangs and fails to create the tag.

I have just updated to the most recent version, currently 1.7.7.22907, but this has no affect.

Is this an application issue or a problem with my SVN server? The SVN server is hosted externally.

Comment: Do you get any errors so far? It'd be helpful to check server logs.

BTW what's the behavior with the command-line SVN client?

Comment: I also experienced this exact same error, but in older versions, when I upgraded to 1.7.7.22907 it disappeared.

Comment: @bahrep It works when using the command line when doing a `svn copy`.

Comment: @allie I have upgraded to the latest version of TortoiseSVN but the problem persists. I have reverted to using the command line to create a release tag. Luckily I can still do a diff of the code using the application though.